# Load list from another list in one line

Tags: vb.net

I cannot figure out how to populate one list with another list in one line.

My function `GetList` is retreiving `List(Of Decimal)`.

What I have tried so far is:

```
Dim somelist As New List(Of Decimal) From {MyObject.GetListOfDecimal()}
```

Comment: Dim newList = List1.Concat(List2).Concat(productCollection3).ToList()

Comment: Do you want to copy the list or do you want to store the result of `GetListOfDecimal()`?

Comment: @Markus want to populate new list with what i retreive from my method. Note that method could retreive Nothing as well if nothing in db.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer something is wrong with your query.. dont get it.

Comment: What is the return type of `GetListOfDecimal`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway List(Of Decimal)

Comment: In that case, then `Dim somelist As New List(Of Decimal) = MyObject.GetListOfDecimal()`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway tried already but i got error that "End of statment excpected"

Comment: @Bugs that was it !

Comment: @Bugs - Thanks for the correction.  I forgot to remove the New when I copied the code.

Answer (score 0):

To assign the return value of `GetListOfDecimal()` to a new `List(Of Decimal)` this is the code you require:

```
Dim somelist As List(Of Decimal) = MyObject.GetListOfDecimal()
```

You don't require the `New` keyword as you are directly assigning the list to it.